# dell 17 5755 with ubuntu 16.04.01

Tags: suspend

i just bought a dell laptop ,i installed ubuntu 16.04 . i fixeditso when i close the lid  i can still use the laptop. i noticed when i closed the lid of the laptop it goes blank  but  its still on my hdtv . i figurrd it went into hibernation, but how can i use the laptop in hibernation mode . did i just turn the laptop monitor off but the laptop itself is still running , and will it hurt my laptop to use it this way ??? its hooked up with the hdmi port thru my surround sound system in the blu ray hdmi slot.  so if i want to watch regular tv i press cable on the remote and when i press  dvd button  the laptop picture is instantly there. so ,is my laptop running non stop ???

Answer (score 0):

you answered your own question  "I fixed it so I can use the laptop when the lid is closed".  the computer is still running. closing the lid only turns off the screen, you can change this behavior in system setting.